# Работает одно ядро CPU при вычислениях на Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, cpu

В анаконде при выполнении кода с библиотеками XGBoost или LightGBM работает только одно ядро CPU. Jupyter Notebook так устроен и лучше исполнять всё например в Visual Studio?

Comment: А сколько потоков запущено?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166401/5741205

Comment: Антон, ну видимо один поток на 1 ядро. Максим, спасибо, понял про ограничения XGBoost, буду исследовать дальше, LightGBM же майкрософтовцы рекомендуют в Visual Studio использовать.